# mpirun Command Issues in the wsl2 Environment

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, openmpi, mpi4py, mpich

When using mpirun, the process is not created normally and the size is always zero. However, mpi works normally when mpirun.mpich is used.
mpirun [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1mWy.png)
mpirun.mpich [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUIHd.png)

How can I work like the mpirun.mpich result when I use mpirun?

Executing the mpi4py.get_config() command resulted in the following results.
{'mpicc': '/usr/bin/mpicc', 'mpicxx': '/usr/bin/mpicxx', 'mpifort': '/usr/bin/mpifort', 'mpif90': '/usr/bin/mpif90', 'mpif77': '/usr/bin/mpif77'}

I heard that both MPICH and OpenMPI versions are installed for MPI, but I'm not sure exactly what the problem is.